# How to automatically show file list after slash in attribute src and href in WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

In VS Code, file list will automatically show after file path or slash like the vscode.gif below, meanwhile in WebStorm, you have to input at least a letter or dot to trigger the suggestion (webstorm.gif).

Is there any setting or plugin in WebStorm can add this feature? It's really convenient and gives me a better coding experience, thanks!

VS Code:
[image: VSCode]

WebStorm:
[image: WebStorm]

Comment: You have to either start typing a name or hit `Ctrl+space` to open the completion popup, there is no way to get it shown automatically

Comment: so bad:( thanks anyway~

Comment: If you use `Ctrl+Space` two times in a row, it should list all possible completions at once (full path) .. so it's bit easier to select the right one if you know the final file name.